# ntop: INTERFACES is not defined, please run 'dpkg-reconfigure ntop' and ntop is broken or not fully installed

Tags: dpkg, ntop

I am go into a dead loop of install and configure ntop. It tells me `ntop: INTERFACES is not defined, please run 'dpkg-reconfigure ntop'` on startup, but this command leads to `ntop is broken or not fully installed`. Is there any way to manually reconfigure ntop?

Comment: Have you tried: `sudo apt-get purge ntop; sudo apt-get install ntop;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**sudo apt-get purge ntop; sudo apt-get install ntop**

Then the follow screen popps:

**Package configuration

┌─────────────────────────┤ Configuring ntop ├─────────────────────────┐
│ Please enter a comma-separated list of interfaces that ntop should   │
│ listen on.                                                           │
│                                                                      │
│ Interfaces for ntop to listen on:                                    │
│                                                                      │
│ none________________________________________________________________ │
│                                                                      │
│                                                                  │
│                                                                      │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

You can get the interface name if you click on the Network Manager in your top panel and select Connection Information. Near the top, you'll see something like "Interface: Ethernet (eth0)". If that's the connection you want to monitor, you'll enter "eth0". (Answer copied and pasted from answered Nov 1 at 19:41Jo-Erlend Schinstad)

I hope I was able to help you.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove it by typing

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ntop
```

reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install ntop
```

If this don't helps tell us please!

Comment: I've got `ntop: INTERFACES is not defined, please run 'dpkg-reconfigure ntop'` again.

Comment: and can you run dpkg-reconfigure ntop now?

Comment: No, I tells me `ntop is broken or not fully installed`